# Expand tuple with vs without loop

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm following an exercise from the *Hands-on machine learning* book by *Aurelien Geron*.

assume `data` is a dataframe:

```
income_cat  index
0         5.0      0
1         5.0      1
2         5.0      2
3         5.0      3
4         5.0      4

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

**Option A (from book):**

```
for test_indices, train_indices in split.split(data, data.income_cat):
    print(test_indices, train_indices)
```

**Option B:**

```
 test_indices, train_indices = split.split(data, data.income_cat)
 print(test_indices, train_indices)
```

**Why doesn't option B work?** This is a python question more than a sklearn question.

A tuple should be expanded both with a loop or without, what could I be missing?
The only difference between options A and B is the for loop.

Output from option A:

```
[4 2 1 0] [3]
```

Output from Option B:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StratifiedShuffleSplit.split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.split) returns a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) not a list. In the `for` loop under the hood there is called `__next__` method on the generator and it returns the next element of the sequence (that generator eventually generates). This returned element unpacks into two variables: `test_indices, train_indices`.

You can achieve the same result by calling `__next__` explicitly using helper function `next()`:

```
 test_indices, train_indices = next(split.split(data, data.income_cat))
```